# Putty maintenance

Tags: putty

The supervisor has asked the team to maintain all the putty logs, which we currently do by manually setting the logs. However, we often get new servers, and sometime switch computers to a fresh one.

Is there are any way where we could do the following :

1. Set putty ( by default ) to capture logs for all new saved sessions.
2. Rotate logs on weekly/monthly basis.
3. Carry settings and logs to new machine.

Thanks, John

Comment: You'll probably need to edit the source code accordingly, then compile accordingly.  Source code can be obtained from here (see near the end of the page):  http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 3):

1. [set up default settings, save them and copy it over on install](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-saving)
2. use task scheduler
3. save settings and move over to the new box. maybe use an SVN for logs...

Comment: Thanks for reply, dont you've anything which could all the tasks at one go. I know this is lot, however it would be go, as this will used by the team, and not just for me. Usually, what happens is that, team members do not follow the putty logging strickly, and they just saw they forget to put the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Portable Putty](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/putty_portable). Everytime you move to a new computer you just copy it over. There are also some [addons](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/08/turbocharge-putty-with-12-powerful-add-ons-software-for-geeks-3/) that prevent putty to write to registry and write things to files instead. Eventually you could try using Putty from one central location (and everyone would be doing the same) but I didn't tested this so hard to say what would be the effect of this.

Comment: We've run non-portable PuTTY from a network share for years (without logging, but that shouldn't matter). So I'd say Portable PuTTY, on a share, with all sessions logging to a share, and a Group Policy Preference putting a link to that particular PuTTY on the desktop.